# Gitlab, pipeline failed for branch - what does it actually mean? Does it affect my commit?

Tags: android, gitlab

I created a new branch of my Gitlab repository and pushed my files to it. Soon afterwards I got an email saying "Pipeline has failed for master2".

What does it actually mean? What action was unsuccessful? And most importantly - does it mean something didn't work with my commit and other persons might have problems looking into my updated project?

Android studio marked all my changed files as up to date and I can see my changes in Gitlab so I guess it's fine but it makes me a bit confused - what exactly went wrong here if my only target was to commit files to repository and it seems to have been successful?

Comment: I just got the same message when I pushed a new Rust project to a brand new GitLab repo (created via push). It looks like it thought I wanted "Auto DevOps" enabled by default, which I've never used, but it sounds like it tried to automatically push my project to Heroku and build it. Since the build failed, it automatically disabled Auto DevOps on the project, so the message stopped appearing on subsequent pushes.

Answer (score 8):

Your project root folder might has a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it's a configuration file for GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

When you have this file in your project root folder, GitLab will run the CI/CD build every time you pushed your change to GitLab. It will run the script in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to build the project.

If the build failed then GitLab will send you an email and told you what's wrong with the build. It doesn't affect your project and commits.